# can i used craft.entries.section into my Controller

Tags: plugin-development, controller

I am new in Craft CMS and this is my first plugin. Below is my code to get products.

```
{% craft.entries.section('products').limit(9) %}
```

This code is working fine but can I use this code in my controller for getting products?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use ElementCriteria in your controller, this is how to go about it:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section('products');
$criteria->limit = 9;

$products = $criteria->find();
```

Read [this page](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) for more info on the subject.